# ActiveRoomModel

Tags: c#

Could someone tell me how I can improve this please? It's similar to my other question just another version of it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sahara.Base.Game.Rooms
{
    internal class ActiveRoomModel : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly bool _clubOnly;
        private readonly int _doorX;
        private readonly int _doorY;
        private readonly double _doorZ;
        private readonly int _doorDirection;
        private string _modelHeightmap;
        private int _modelSizeX;
        private int _modelSizeY;
        private short[,] _squareFloorHeight;
        private byte[,] _squareSeatRotation;
        private SquareState[,] _squareState;
        private RoomModel _staticModel;
        private readonly string _dependantHeightmap;

        public ActiveRoomModel(RoomModel staticModel)
        {
            _staticModel = staticModel;
            _doorX = staticModel.DoorX;
            _doorY = staticModel.DoorY;
            _doorZ = staticModel.DoorZ;
            _doorDirection = staticModel.DoorDirection;
            _modelHeightmap = staticModel.Heightmap;
            _modelSizeX = staticModel.ModelSizeX;
            _modelSizeY = staticModel.ModelSizeY;
            _clubOnly = staticModel.ClubOnly;
            _dependantHeightmap = string.Empty;
            _squareState = new SquareState[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            _squareFloorHeight = new short[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            _squareSeatRotation = new byte[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];

            for (var y = 0; y < _modelSizeY; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < _modelSizeX; x++)
                {
                    if (x > (staticModel.ModelSizeX - 1) || y > (staticModel.ModelSizeY - 1))
                    {
                        _squareState[x, y] = SquareState.Blocked;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _squareState[x, y] = staticModel.SquareState[x, y];
                        _squareFloorHeight[x, y] = staticModel.SquareFloorHeight[x, y];
                        _squareSeatRotation[x, y] = staticModel.SquareSeatRotation[x, y];
                    }
                }
            }

            var floorMap = new StringBuilder();

            for (var y = 0; y < _modelSizeY; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < _modelSizeX; x++)
                {
                    if (x == _doorX && y == _doorY)
                    {
                        floorMap.Append(_doorZ > 9 ? ((char)(87 + _doorZ)).ToString() : _doorZ.ToString());
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (_squareState[x, y] == SquareState.Blocked)
                    {
                        floorMap.Append('x');
                        continue;
                    }

                    double height = _squareFloorHeight[x, y];
                    floorMap.Append(height > 9 ? ((char)(87 + height)).ToString() : height.ToString());
                }

                floorMap.Append(Convert.ToChar(13));
            }

            _dependantHeightmap = floorMap.ToString();
        }

        public string DependantHeightmap => _dependantHeightmap;
        public bool DoorCorrect => _doorX <= _squareFloorHeight.GetUpperBound(0) && _doorY <= _squareFloorHeight.GetUpperBound(1);

        public void AppendXCordinate()
        {
            _modelSizeX++;
            UpdateSquareArrays();
        }

        public void AppendYCordinate()
        {
            _modelSizeY++;
            UpdateSquareArrays();
        }

        public void CreateMap(int x, int y)
        {
            _modelSizeX = x;
            _modelSizeY = y;
            UpdateSquareArrays();
        }

        private void UpdateSquareArrays()
        {
            var newSqState = new SquareState[_modelSizeX + 1, _modelSizeY + 1];
            var newSqFloorHeight = new short[_modelSizeX + 1, _modelSizeY + 1];
            var newSqSeatRot = new byte[_modelSizeX + 1, _modelSizeY + 1];

            for (var y = 0; y < _modelSizeY; y++)
            {
                for (var x = 0; x < _modelSizeX; x++)
                {
                    if (x > (_staticModel.ModelSizeX - 1) || y > (_staticModel.ModelSizeY - 1))
                    {
                        newSqState[x, y] = SquareState.Blocked;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newSqState[x, y] = _squareState[x, y];
                        newSqFloorHeight[x, y] = _squareFloorHeight[x, y];
                        newSqSeatRot[x, y] = _squareSeatRotation[x, y];
                    }
                }
            }

            _squareState = newSqState;
            _squareFloorHeight = newSqFloorHeight;
            _squareSeatRotation = newSqSeatRot;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Array.Clear(_squareState, 0, _squareState.Length);
            _squareState = null;

            Array.Clear(_squareFloorHeight, 0, _squareFloorHeight.Length);
            _squareFloorHeight = null;

            Array.Clear(_squareSeatRotation, 0, _squareSeatRotation.Length);
            _squareSeatRotation = null;

            _staticModel = null;
            _modelHeightmap = null;
        }
    }
}
```

RoomModel:

```
using System;

namespace Sahara.Base.Game.Rooms
{
    internal sealed class RoomModel
    {
        private readonly bool _clubOnly;
        private readonly int _doorX;
        private readonly int _doorY;
        private readonly double _doorZ;
        private readonly int _doorDirection;
        private readonly string _modelHeightmap;
        private readonly int _modelSizeX;
        private readonly int _modelSizeY;
        private readonly int _wallHeight;
        private readonly short[,] _squareFloorHeight;
        private readonly byte[,] _squareSeatRotation;
        private readonly SquareState[,] _squareState;
        private readonly string _modelFurniMap;
        private readonly bool _publicPool;
        private readonly byte[,] _roomModelEffects;

        public RoomModel(bool clubOnly, int doorPositionX, int doorPositionY, int wallHeight, double doorPositionZ, int doorDirection, string modelHeightMap, string modelFurniMap, string poolMap)
        {
            _doorX = doorPositionX;
            _doorY = doorPositionY;
            _doorZ = doorPositionZ;
            _doorDirection = doorDirection;
            _wallHeight = wallHeight;
            _modelHeightmap = modelHeightMap.ToLower();
            _modelFurniMap = modelFurniMap;

            if (poolMap != string.Empty)
            {
                _publicPool = true;
                _roomModelEffects = new byte[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            }

            var temporaryHeightmap = _modelHeightmap.Split(Convert.ToChar(13));

            _modelSizeX = temporaryHeightmap[0].Length;
            _modelSizeY = temporaryHeightmap.Length;
            _clubOnly = clubOnly;
            _squareState = new SquareState[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            _squareFloorHeight = new short[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];
            _squareSeatRotation = new byte[_modelSizeX, _modelSizeY];

            for (var y = _modelSizeY - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            {
                var line = temporaryHeightmap[y].Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);

                var x = 0;
                foreach (var modelSquare in line)
                {
                    if (modelSquare == 'x')
                    {
                        _squareState[x, y] = Rooms.SquareState.Blocked;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _squareState[x, y] = Rooms.SquareState.Open;
                        _squareFloorHeight[x, y] = Sahara.GetServer().GetUtility().ParseModelSquare(modelSquare);
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }

        public int DoorX => _doorX;
        public int DoorY => _doorY;
        public double DoorZ => _doorZ;
        public int DoorDirection => _doorDirection;
        public string Heightmap => _modelHeightmap;
        public int ModelSizeX => _modelSizeX;
        public int ModelSizeY => _modelSizeY;
        public bool ClubOnly => _clubOnly;
        public SquareState[,] SquareState => _squareState;
        public short[,] SquareFloorHeight => _squareFloorHeight;
        public byte[,] SquareSeatRotation => _squareSeatRotation;
        public bool PublicPool => _publicPool;
    }
}
```

SquareState:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sahara.Base.Game.Rooms
{
    public enum SquareState
    {
        Open = 0,
        Blocked = 1,
        Seat = 2,
        Pool = 3,
        Vip = 4
    }


}
```

Comment: If you've created multiple accounts, please ask for them to be merged: codereview.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Please include `SquareState` && `RoomModel``in your question's body.

Comment: I have added them.

Comment: Welcome to CR! Your question is *okay* - it would be *better* if you included a bit of a description of what each component is doing, and what the overall purpose is. Cheers!

Comment: Your two questions are so similar that it's really hard to tell the difference between them. Could you write something more about this implementation? Is this just another class or a follow-up?

Comment: Follow up but another version.

Comment: _Follow up but another version._ It can't be both. Either-or.

Comment: If it's a follow-up, provide a link back to the original question for clarity. You haven't posted much yet, but think what would happen if a user with over 50 questions would say 'follow-up on my other question'. *Which* other question? Your only other question is more recent than this one.

Answer (score 3):

## `RoomModel` class

- In C# 6, we have readonly-only property. Instead of writing:

  > ```
  > private readonly bool _clubOnly;
  > public int DoorX => _doorX;
  >
  > ctor(...)
  > {
  >     _doorX = doorPositionX;
  > }
  > ```

  You can just write:

  ```
  public int DoorX { get; }

  ctor(...)
  {
      DoorX = doorPositionX;
  }
  ```
- > `var temporaryHeightmap = _modelHeightmap.Split(Convert.ToChar(13));`

  You should avoid using `Convert.To/*priminitive types here*/` when possible, as it doesn't catch nonsense value until you execute it. For instance, `Convert.ToChar(-13)` will throw when you execute it, but `(char)-13` won't even compile!
  Also what is `13`? If we look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), it will tell us that 13 is <kbd>CR</kbd>(Cariage Return) which is `\r` in c# literal.

  ```
  var temporaryHeightmap = _modelHeightmap.Split('\r');
  ```
- In the constructor:

  > ```
  > var x = 0;
  > foreach (var modelSquare in line)
  > {
  >     if (modelSquare == 'x')
  >     {
  >         _squareState[x, y] = Rooms.SquareState.Blocked;
  >     }
  >     else
  >     {
  >         _squareState[x, y] = Rooms.SquareState.Open;
  >         _squareFloorHeight[x, y] = Sahara.GetServer().GetUtility().ParseModelSquare(modelSquare);
  >     }
  >     x++;
  > }
  > ```

  This block can be rewritten as:

  ```
  for(int x = 0; x < line.length; x++)
  {
      var modelSquare = line[x];
      // ...
  }
  ```

## `ActiveRoomModel` class

- Quoting MSDN on [`IDisposable.Dispose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx):

  > Use this method to close or release **unmanaged resources such as files, streams, and handles** held by an instance of the class that implements this interface. By convention, this method is used for all tasks associated with freeing resources held by an object, or preparing an object for reuse.

  It is unnecessary to release these arrays and object references, as the garbage collector will take care of them for you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818329/c-sharp-how-can-i-destroy-a-temporary-string-array-before-it-gets-garbage-collec) for detailed explanation.
- This section of code should be extracted into a function or a pre-filled dictionary:

  ```
  `height > 9 ? ((char)(87 + /* variable */)).ToString() : height.ToString()`
  ```